# Wiring Help Replacing a Two Switch Ceiling Fan and Light with Only a Single Light Fixture--See Photos

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light

At the ceiling box where the ceiling fan/light there is:
White Wire
Black Wire
Red Wire
Ground Wire

The 2 wall switches.
The Left switch powered the fan.
The right switch powered the light.

I am installing a single light fixture that has Black, White, and Ground Wire.

How do I re-wire at the switches? What do I need to do to run the new light fixture off of one of the wall switches? How do I properly/safely "Cap-Off" the switch not in use?

Also both of the wall switches the black plastic housings are both cracked pretty good. What types of switches are these so I can replace? Especially the one that will be actually in use.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good on ya' for including a clear, focused pic of the wiring _before_ you took it all apart! You'd be amazed at how many people don't bother with that... While you're waiting for an answer, take the [tour] so you can learn how the Q&A format here differs from the general "discussion board" format you may be used to.

Comment: The switch with the red is toast cut or remove red from the switch. 
Remove black jumper between switches, pig tail all the blacks and use the jumper removed between the 2 switches to connect to the switch. 
Get a blank /switch cover plate like Jack shows in his answer. Cap the red at both the switch location and in the ceiling box.  Use the black for the light and this will meet code.

Answer (score 3):

Lets eliminate the switch with the red wire. Remove the two black wires on the red wire switch, one from the screw terminal and one from the backstab and wire nut them together. Remove the red wire and put a wire nut on it.

Now get a new single pole single throw, standard toggle switch since you stated both switches were cracked. Remove the black wire loop from the switch screw terminal and the wire from the backstab next to it. Pigtail them with a small piece of black wire and connect it to the new switch. Remove the other black wire from the backstab at the other end of the switch and bend a shepherd's hook on the stripped wire and screw it to the other terminal on the new switch. Ground the switch with a piece of #14 wire. Now mount the switch and get a cover similar to the one shown below.

To remove the backstab wires, shove a small screwdriver into the slot by the wires and put the wire out.

[image]

At the ceiling box, remove the red wire and wire nut it. Connect the black wire from the box to the black wire from the light fixture with a wire nut. connect the white wires together the same way. Connect the two ground wires together with a wire nut.

Comment: The very first step I am a little confused of why wire nutting those two wires at all because its just bridging between the two switches with the short black wire. But my biggest concern is the 2nd step there are 2 black wires going into backstabs and 2 black wires at the screw point (one being the short bridged wire to the other switch).

Comment: Added a better pic above. Thank you:-)

Comment: The feed comes into the box and loops around the first switch to feed it and then goes to the second switch to feed it. Now both switches are hot. The wires going into the backstabs are tied to the hot screw terminals so they are now hot too and they go to other lights, outlets in the room/house.  You can pigtail them all together and connect a wire to the switch. I was just trying to make it simple and leave it so you could add a switch back in the future in so desired.

Comment: I missed the backstabbed hot black on the first switch. Your new picture clarified it and I edited my answer.The important thing to remember is that the three black wires from the bottom of those switches need to be connected together with an addition piece of wire going to the switch

Comment: Perfect:-) Very clear and concise.

Comment: I'll need to go out and grab a new switch and plate. I have some Romex 12/2.....I suppose that is sufficient to make the new short pigtail.

Comment: You can use the one good switch from what I see, but you will need a new cover plate. (Get rid of the backstabs, pigtail)+

Comment: @EdBeal  The OP states that both switches have cracked black housings. :-)

Comment: I did not see that but I guess it’s never a bad idea for a new switch since today’s switches have contacts that arc on make and break.

Comment: Just got back. Grabbed a new switch. Didn't have that style plate so i'll have to order. This new switch says single pole 20A on it......both the old ones say 15A on em. Didnt think about it when i grabbed it......Is that still cool? I can just run the new ground from the switch to those grounds in the back of the box right? Thanks guys

Comment: @FrankTank  Your new switch is rated for 20 amps. It's a bit hardier and more inline with a commercial grade switch. Yes, run the ground from the group in the back to the green screw on the switch.

Comment: Added some pics. Taped to "label" em in case i ever revert  (doubt I will). Hard to see in  final photo but the black and white taped wire is pigtailed in with the blacks.   Light powers right up:-) I noticed when i bundled the wires and pushing the new switch back in.......one of the white wires coming into the box has very small pucker-like slit in the wire exposing it ever so slightly (width of my pinky nail if it's even that much. Its right next to one of the open ground wires. At the edge of the knockout/strain relief thing...dont know how i'm gonna get my fingers in there to wrap it?

Comment: Could you take one last glance at the recent 3 pics I added? I just want to be certain. Always second guessing when i do this stuff. I was able to get electrical tape to cover the slit in the white wire. Only had 12 gauge to do the ground wire. Wrapped a little tape around the ground wire nut and the black wires wire nut. Really appreciate the help guys!

Comment: @FrankTank  Typical newbe mistake but OK. You don't need to wrap any electrical tape around wire nutted connections. If the wire is stripped right and the wire nut screwed on correctly,  then no copper should be showing and no contact will be made with other wires. 12 for the ground is OK.  The slit in the NB neutral would have been done by the installer when they stripped off the outer insulation. Taping it is all you could really do. Better the neutral  than the hot.  Surprised you had to order the switch plate... they are pretty common.

Comment: I know....think i have only ever used the Big Blue wire nuts like 1 time before. Seemed to me the ones that were on previously were to small but i dont know. Blue said minimum 3 x 12's so. The smaller ones seemed like they were shredding the copper. But I put the bottom 3 black wires and pigtailed em to the bottom of the new switch (says neutral position on the box) and the top black one to the top (Hot on the box) of the new switch. Just wanna be safe is all. Really thank you!! Posted my initial question on another electric forum and they all said call an electrician.

Comment: @FrankTank If you expect to ever do electrical work again, having a selection of wire nuts is a good idea and inexpensive. Different colors are different sizes and they're rated for different combinations/counts of wires. Having a variety means you always have the right size, which means you can always get them good & tight and skip the worry and the taping. I bought a box each of red, orange & yellow 25+ years ago and still have many left despite _many_ electrical projects...

Comment: Yeah for sure. I've had a couple bins still kickin since like 2001 haha